# jQuery - hide only visible images (before load) on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, google-chrome-extension, hide

I'm developing a Chrome extension, and require a functionality such that I want to get all visible images as soon as possible (before they load), hide them and set some attribute. I've been trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img:visible').each(function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(this).attr('data-internalid', guid());
    });
});
```

But while debugging, I noticed that it's not even iterating through the loop. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried checking what `$('img:visible')` returns ?

Comment: It returns this
[prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "img:visible", jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function…]context: documentlength: 0prevObject: n.fn.init[1]selector: "img:visible"__proto__: n[0]

Comment: May be try an alternative => 1) Have a class for images you'd like to set attributes to, 2) Set `display:none;` to that class in CSS, 3) On load, set your attributes and then display those images.

Comment: The interesting thing is that, when I remove ":visible" it works. And also when I do the same $('img:visible') on browser console (after the page fully loaded) it returns valid image objects

Comment: @LShetty I may try that also

Comment: And also, from the doc: _Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero._. So, on doc ready all images are not loaded, which could be the reason for failure. You may want to try `$(window).on('load', ... `

Comment: Hm.. This makes sense enough. I've tried $(window).load() it works, but I needed to do this before images load. I'm just going to try the alternative you mentioned.

Comment: @LShetty You should make that into an answer

Comment: @LShetty I tried your alternative and also changed from $(document).ready() to $(window).load() and it works great (with small exceptions when I have a lot of images in a page). You may post it as an answer and I will accept it as a resolved problem. I guess the main problem was that images was not being counted as visible (":visible") before they load. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as I mentioned in my comments

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.

So, one of your options would be to use

```
$(window).on('load', function() { ... });
```

You may also try an alternative, such as the following.

1. Have a class for all the images you'd later like to set attributes to.
2. Set `display:none;` to that particular class in CSS.
3. On load (look at the first option), set your attributes and then display those images, either by removing the class (recommended) or setting inline styles (not pretty).

Hope that was clear :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function (index) {
    $('img:visible').each(function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(this).attr('data-internalid', "test"); /*instead of guid().I think that function have some problem.Make sure it is defined or loaded properly*/
    });
});
```

The problem is with your guid() function.This code works fine on firefox and chrome.Please check the function.If the problem is not solved, then update your jquery if it is offline else please provide guid() function.

```js
$(function(){
  //$("#btn").click(function(){
       $('img:visible').each(function() {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
        $(this).attr('data-internalid', "test");
    });
  //  });
  
  });
```

```css
img{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:10px
}
span{
  display:block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/o/d/I/G/A/smily-hi.png">
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/o/d/I/G/A/smily-hi.png">
<img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/w/o/d/I/G/A/smily-hi.png">
<span id="btn">Click me</span>
```

Comment: As I said, it doesn't iterate through the loop at all. The function it's very simple and it's loaded properly.

Comment: That one is tested in chrome and firefox

Comment: I didn't make it "not useful" and for the sake of asking, I just tried it, but It didn't work. I also commented that line and still the same.

Comment: K.Sory for that.Now check it.And run the code snippet.

Comment: Please read well what I need first, than answer. I asked this as I needed on $(document).ready() not in button click !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75924/discussion-between-aneesh-rs-and-trim).

Comment: $(function(){}) is the shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){})

Answer (score -3):

Check what returns `$(this)`,
use console log for it.