# jquery changing image height changes images to wrong height

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, dom

I have several images on a page. Every image except the first has a class of "index_image".  I want each image to have the same height as the first image.  Here is the first image:

```
<img alt="Image 1" id="ride_image" 
 src="image-1.png">
```

Here is the javascript that does the image changing:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var image_1_height = $('#ride_image').height();
        alert(image_1_height);
        $('.index_image').height(image_1_height); 
    });
</script>
```

It is changing all of the image's height to zero instead of the height of the first image.  I think this has something to do with the code being called before the images height is set, because first there are no images on the page, then the alert appears, and then the first image appears.  The rest of the images heights are changed to zero right away so they never appear.

How do I change the height properly?

Comment: Here is a related answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29793301/jquery-hide-only-visible-images-before-load-on-document-ready/29794650#29794650

Comment: Somebody wrote a correct answer and then deleted it.  It is similar to the answer by @nayish, except it said to call .load on the window object, so that all images are loaded before the javascript runs.

Answer (score 2):

The height of an image is only set when the image returns and not when the document is ready.

So when you try catching the image height on document ready the image is not yet fetched and so its height is 0.

You can use the first image's `load()` function to bind to so that when it is loaded it's height will be set for the rest.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var image_1_height = $('#ride_image').height();
        if (image_1_height !== 0) {
            alert(image_1_height);
            $('.index_image').height(image_1_height); 
        } else {
            $('#ride_image').load(function() {
                var image_1_height = $('#ride_image').height();
                alert(image_1_height);
                $('.index_image').height(image_1_height); 
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

Working JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nayish/ehw6ufyq/3/

Since images that were previously loaded will act faster and not trigger the load function. So the solution is to first try on document ready, if it is not yet set (height is set to 0) then we will wait for the image to load. Problem can be seen in the caveats section of the jquery load api page: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/.

Comment: An alternative to using the `.load()` event (it never really has worked for me, tbh) might be using `setInterval` to check every so often for a height > 0.